# Understanding an equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am trying to understand an equation from the paper "Dynamic Model for generating Synthetic ECG signal" (http://web.mit.edu/~gari/www/papers/ieeetbe50p289.pdf). The equation is:

$$S(f) = \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sqrt{2\pi c_1^2}}\exp\left({\frac{(f-f_1)^2}{2c_1^2}}\right) + \frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sqrt{2\pi c_2^2}}\exp\left({\frac{(f-f_2)^2}{2c_2^2}}\right)$$}
My understanding of the equation is as follows: 
1. Linear combination of two normally distributed random variable , gives rise to a normal random process (not able to prove it).
2. If the above process is Wide Sense Stationary, then I can take its Power Spectral Density(PSD).
3. PSD is then simply the fourier transform squared, which gives rise to the equation.

However, I am not at all sure if my understanding is correct. So any guidance in the form of steps or proofs are most welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: A constant linear combination of two JOINTLY normally distributed random variables is normally distributed.  In particular, a constant linear combination of two INDEPENDENT normally distributed random variables is normally distributed.  But that has nothing to do with the equation you've shown us.  That shows a linear combination of two normal DENSITIES, not of two normally distributed random variables.  The density of a linear combination of two independent normally distributed random variables is a _convolution_ of their densities, not a linear combination of their densities. $\qquad$

Comment: They seem to have omitted two minus signs. $\qquad$